# Is there a way to return an encrypted text and retain the punctuation in python (without using Regex)

Tags: python, encryption, text

I'm working on piece of code and I'm trying to open a text file, encrypt the words and return an encrypted text while preserving the original text punctuation. I've coded the encryption part but I can't find a best way to retain the punctuation. I DON'T want to use Regex. Please see a copy of my code below:

```
import sys

def get_plain_file():
    # opens the plain text file and returns the text
    if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
        filename = 'plain.txt'
    with open(filename, mode='r') as source:
        text = source.read()
        source.close()
    return text

def shift_dict(shift):
    # define who to shift the characters in the word:
    ch_dict = {}
    for i in range(97, 123):
        if i+shift < 123:
            ch_dict.update({chr(i): (chr(i+shift))})
        else:
            ch_dict.update({chr(i): (chr(i+shift-26))})
    return ch_dict

def encrypt(shift):
    # Returns Encrypted text BUT delete all of punctioations
    word_list = get_plain_file().split()
    encr_list = []
    sdict = shift_dict(shift)
    for i in range(len(word_list)):
        word = word_list[i].lower()
        new_list = [sdict[c] for c in word if c in sdict.keys()]
        new_word = "".join(new_list)
        encr_list.append(new_word)
    encrypted_text = " ".join(encr_list)
    return encrypted_text
```

Comment: I wouldn't bother splitting the file into words. For each character, if it's in your encryption dictionary, replace it with the substitute character. Otherwise leave it the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commented above, but I think this deserves an actual answer

```
text = get_plain_file()
encrypted = [sdict.get(c, c) for c in text]
return ''.join(encrypted)
```

Each character is replaced by its encryption.  Each non-character stays itself.  This uses the `.get()` function, which returns the value in the dictionary if it's there, and otherwise the default.

This also works as a one-liner:

```
return ''.join(sdict.get(c, c) for c in text)
```

Comment: thanks Frank. that worked well. I only modified my shift dictionary to include the capital letters as well.